# Changing the look and feel more than once?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel

I want to use a windows look and feel as the main appearance while making the progress bar the nimbus look and feel.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mix most of the UIs how you you want. Either create your own lookandfeel class which sets all the UI elements as system and the progress as nimbus or use the setUI method explicitly with the NimbusUI class for the progress bar. This is how applications have custom looking components.

Keepin mind with swing you can do almost anything you want since most of the drawing is handled within the Swing framework.